# IMGSRV error android

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I have created an android app which plays stream from the internet. When HOME button is pressed while images re being downloaded I get the following error:

```
05-16 08:22:11.768: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: SGXGetFreeDeviceSyncList: Get free DeviceSyncList timeout.
05-16 08:22:11.768: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: HW operation timeout occurred.
05-16 08:22:11.768: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: MapperLogSyncObjects: Dumping buffered log messages..
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: No permissions for 'dumpsys SurfaceFlinger'.
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: Full contents of /d/sync:
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: objs:
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: --------------
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: surfaceflinger pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x277df/0x277df
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126781.268794: ID=2186640, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277b6, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00920c, ROC DevVA=0xef009214, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00921c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.563379: ID=2186687, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277d9, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00416c, ROC DevVA=0xef004174, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00417c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.566659: ID=2186688, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277da, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x1, WOC DevVA=0xef0088c4, ROC DevVA=0xef0088cc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0088d4
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.566663: ID=2186692, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277dc, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001c34, ROC DevVA=0xef001c3c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001c44
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.566787: ID=2186694, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277dd, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00407c, ROC DevVA=0xef004084, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00408c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.566865: ID=2186696, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277de, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040f4, ROC DevVA=0xef0040fc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004104
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.566985: ID=2186698, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f54, ROC DevVA=0xef001f5c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f64
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.271230: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.271279: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.271396: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: pvr_queue_proc sw_sync: 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@33916.396589: 420848 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.060290: 1152262 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152268 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152268 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152269 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152269 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152270 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152270 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152271 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152271 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152272 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: 1152272 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: Thread-128 pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@20.935187: ID=123, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x0, parent=f012c580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0017fc, ROC DevVA=0xef001804, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00180c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: ndroid.systemui pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0xa35d/0xa35d
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@25.342342: ID=207, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x3, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x6a0c/0x6a0c, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x2, WOC DevVA=0xef0047ac, ROC DevVA=0xef0047b4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0047bc
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@33916.352858: ID=207, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x3, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x6a0c/0x6a0c, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x2, WOC DevVA=0xef0047ac, ROC DevVA=0xef0047b4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0047bc
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126781.268793: ID=2186628, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0xa35b, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001504, ROC DevVA=0xef00150c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001514
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.263115: ID=2186699, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0xa35d, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004004, ROC DevVA=0xef00400c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004014
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.263116: ID=2186699, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0xa35d, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004004, ROC DevVA=0xef00400c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004014
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.271393: ID=2186639, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0xa35c, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0041e4, ROC DevVA=0xef0041ec, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0041f4
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: mediaserver pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: oid.inputmethod pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x388/0x388
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@125799.381812: ID=2127432, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x388, parent=f026f300
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x4a/0x4a, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0093ec, ROC DevVA=0xef0093f4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0093fc
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@125799.381813: ID=2127432, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x388, parent=f026f300
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x4a/0x4a, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0093ec, ROC DevVA=0xef0093f4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0093fc
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: earchbox:search pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: m.tibo.upgrader pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x62/0x62
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126781.852026: ID=2186669, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x62, parent=caff1900
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef009194, ROC DevVA=0xef00919c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0091a4
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126781.852027: ID=2186669, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x62, parent=caff1900
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef009194, ROC DevVA=0xef00919c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0091a4
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: com.tibo.webtv pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x54c2/0x54c0
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.236784: ID=2186689, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x54be, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004644, ROC DevVA=0xef00464c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004654
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.674070: ID=2186693, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c0, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004054, ROC DevVA=0xef00405c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004064
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126782.253588: ID=2186691, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x54bf, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001c0c, ROC DevVA=0xef001c14, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001c1c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: ID=2186695, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c1, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040cc, ROC DevVA=0xef0040d4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0040dc
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt signaled@126783.674073: ID=2186693, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c0, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004054, ROC DevVA=0xef00405c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004064
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: ID=2186695, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c1, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.808: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040cc, ROC DevVA=0xef0040d4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0040dc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: .apps.magazines pvr_sync: WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: fences:
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: --------------
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [d7006c00] pvr_egl: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   Thread-128_pt signaled@20.935187: ID=123, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x0, parent=f012c580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0017fc, ROC DevVA=0xef001804, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00180c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc3fea80] pvr_ws_q_17: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@25.342342: ID=207, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x3, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x6a0c/0x6a0c, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x2, WOC DevVA=0xef0047ac, ROC DevVA=0xef0047b4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0047bc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc6450c0] com.android.systemui.ImageWa:0: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@33916.352858: ID=207, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x3, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x6a0c/0x6a0c, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x2, WOC DevVA=0xef0047ac, ROC DevVA=0xef0047b4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0047bc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt signaled@33916.396589: 420848 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e35d0a80] pvr_ws_q_16487: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   oid.inputmethod_pt signaled@125799.381812: ID=2127432, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x388, parent=f026f300
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x4a/0x4a, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0093ec, ROC DevVA=0xef0093f4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0093fc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e35d0540] pvr_cleanup: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   oid.inputmethod_pt signaled@125799.381813: ID=2127432, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x388, parent=f026f300
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x4a/0x4a, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0093ec, ROC DevVA=0xef0093f4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0093fc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [eeb099c0] StatusBar:1: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126781.268794: ID=2186640, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277b6, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00920c, ROC DevVA=0xef009214, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00921c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@126781.268793: ID=2186628, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0xa35b, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001504, ROC DevVA=0xef00150c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001514
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65e9c0] pvr_ws_q_17441: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   m.tibo.upgrader_pt signaled@126781.852026: ID=2186669, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x62, parent=caff1900
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef009194, ROC DevVA=0xef00919c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0091a4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65e4e0] pvr_cleanup: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   m.tibo.upgrader_pt signaled@126781.852027: ID=2186669, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x62, parent=caff1900
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef009194, ROC DevVA=0xef00919c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0091a4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [ddeb1060] pvr_ws_q_3: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.563379: ID=2186687, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277d9, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00416c, ROC DevVA=0xef004174, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00417c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [ddeb1a80] FramebufferSurface:0: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt signaled@126783.060290: 1152262 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.566659: ID=2186688, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277da, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x1, WOC DevVA=0xef0088c4, ROC DevVA=0xef0088cc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0088d4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [ddeb1120] pvr_queue_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152268 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [ddeb1480] com.tibo.webtv/com.tibo.webt:1: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.566663: ID=2186692, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277dc, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001c34, ROC DevVA=0xef001c3c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001c44
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt signaled@126782.236784: ID=2186689, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x54be, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004644, ROC DevVA=0xef00464c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004654
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152268 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: waiter PVRDRMUnprivCmd+0x2a0/0x1840 [pvrsgx]
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65e3c0] pvr_queue_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152269 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [c6bc31e0] pvr_ws_q_17442: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt signaled@126783.674070: ID=2186693, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c0, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004054, ROC DevVA=0xef00405c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004064
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65e720] com.tibo.webtv/com.tibo.webt:2: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.566787: ID=2186694, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277dd, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00407c, ROC DevVA=0xef004084, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00408c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt signaled@126782.253588: ID=2186691, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x54bf, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001c0c, ROC DevVA=0xef001c14, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001c1c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152269 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: waiter PVRDRMUnprivCmd+0x2a0/0x1840 [pvrsgx]
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65eea0] pvr_queue_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152270 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [c6bc3120] pvr_ws_q_17443: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt active: ID=2186695, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c1, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040cc, ROC DevVA=0xef0040d4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0040dc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65e480] com.tibo.webtv/com.tibo.webt:0: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.566865: ID=2186696, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277de, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040f4, ROC DevVA=0xef0040fc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004104
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt signaled@126783.674073: ID=2186693, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c0, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004054, ROC DevVA=0xef00405c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004064
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152270 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [cc65eb40] pvr_queue_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152271 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [c6bc3060] pvr_ws_q_17444: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [c6bc30c0] pvr_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [ddeb1900] com.tibo.webtv/com.tibo.webt:1: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126782.566985: ID=2186698, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f54, ROC DevVA=0xef001f5c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f64
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt active: ID=2186695, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0x54c1, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0040cc, ROC DevVA=0xef0040d4, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0040dc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152271 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734960] pvr_queue_cleanup: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152272 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734a20] com.tibo.webtv/com.tibo.webt:2: active
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   pvr_queue_proc_pt active: 1152272 / 1152267
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   com.tibo.webtv_pt active: ID=2186697, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x54c2, parent=ee292880
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x1/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef001f2c, ROC DevVA=0xef001f34, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001f3c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e17348a0] pvr_ws_q_12184: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@126783.263115: ID=2186699, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0xa35d, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004004, ROC DevVA=0xef00400c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004014
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734de0] pvr_cleanup: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@126783.263116: ID=2186699, refs=2, WOPSnapshot=0xa35d, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004004, ROC DevVA=0xef00400c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef004014
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734a80] pvr_egl: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126783.271230: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734c60] pvr_cleanup: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126783.271279: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: [e1734e40] StatusBar:2: signaled
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   surfaceflinger_pt signaled@126783.271396: ID=2186700, refs=3, WOPSnapshot=0x277df, parent=ef67d600
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00a374, ROC DevVA=0xef00a37c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00a384
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   ndroid.systemui_pt signaled@126783.271393: ID=2186639, refs=1, WOPSnapshot=0xa35c, parent=edfe9580
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:    WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef0041e4, ROC DevVA=0xef0041ec, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0041f4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: Full contents of /proc/pvr/queue:
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: 
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: Command Queues
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: Queue    CmdPtr      Pid Command Size DevInd  DSC  SSC  #Data ...
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: edca8000 edffb300   1887       0  120      1    0    2     32  
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   Sync 0: ROP/ROC: 0x0/0x0 WOP/WOC: 0x1/0x1 ROC-VA: 0xef0040dc WOC-VA: 0xef0040cc
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   Sync 1: ROP/ROC: 0x1/0x1 WOP/WOC: 0x2/0x2 ROC-VA: 0xef001ec4 WOC-VA: 0xef001eb4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: edca8000 edffb378   1887       0  120      1    0    2     32  
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   Sync 0: ROP/ROC: 0x0/0x0 WOP/WOC: 0x1/0x0 ROC-VA: 0xef001f3c WOC-VA: 0xef001f2c
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0:   Sync 1: ROP/ROC: 0x1/0x0 WOP/WOC: 0x2/0x1 ROC-VA: 0xef0046a4 WOC-VA: 0xef004694
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: MapperLogSyncObjects: Dumping all active sync objects..
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: ID=17444, 0xP..MFHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x2/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef004694, ROC DevVA=0xef00469c, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0046a4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: ID=17443, 0xP..MFHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x2/0x2, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x2/0x1, WOC DevVA=0xef001eb4, ROC DevVA=0xef001ebc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef001ec4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: ID=17442, 0xP..MFHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x2/0x2, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x6/0x5, WOC DevVA=0xef0089b4, ROC DevVA=0xef0089bc, ROC2 DevVA=0xef0089c4
05-16 08:22:11.818: E/IMGSRV(29297): :0: ID=7, 0xP..MFHWR=0x00000100, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0xef00152c, ROC DevVA=0xef001534, ROC2 DevVA=0xef00153c
```

I am new to android and this kind of error is not clear to me. Can anybody explain what this error mean?

Comment: You are using some OpenGL type of stuff also or just simply downloading images form server?

Comment: icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
     icon = icon1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);

Comment: I don't understand error doesn't fit with your code. Is this the full stack trace of error? 
The reason I am saying all this is because maximum error you can get is Out of memory using these two lines. Can you try again and paste the full error log.

Comment: I dont know if this is related to images, this happens after the images are downloaded, when video is starting playing and HOME button is pressed then

Comment: ok, can you paste some code snippets that doing your work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77961/discussion-between-thejango-and-maria-agaci).